# How do I compile and link the sample code to get a binary?

Tags: c, arm, linker-scripts

I'm working with a TI Stellaris LM3S1968. This MCU has an ARM Cortex-M3.

I installed a VM on my laptop with Windows 7 on it, and there I installed [GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/). Then I installed [Stellaris Flash Programmer, GUI and command line](http://www.ti.com/tool/lmflashprogrammer). I also installed the [Stellaris FTDI Drivers](http://www.ti.com/tool/lm_ftdi_driver).

Finally, I downloaded and extracted the [EK-LM3S1968 Firmware Development Package](http://www.ti.com/tool/sw-ek-lm3s1968).

In the extracted folder, there are some examples. One of them is blinky. If I go to /StellarisWare/board/ek-lm3s1968/blinky/gcc/ there's a file called blinky.bin. Using the Stellaris Flash Programmer I can hook it up to my computer and flash it, and it'll work. I tried it with various examples and they all worked.

Now my goal would be to compile the sample code provided in /StellarisWare/board/ek-lm3s1968/blinky/, and to flash it. However, I haven't had much luck, as I'm not very experienced with C or programming microcontrollers.

I copied the LM3S1968 libraries from the StellarisWare folder to the compiler's include folder. Then I followed some examples I found online, but I was not successful. This is what I tried:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb blinky.c -nostartfile -T blinky.ld -o blinky.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T blinky.ld -o blinky.out blinky.o
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary blinky.out blinky.bin
```

When I flash this .bin file, it doesn't do anything, the LED just stays on.

I think it's because there's a startup_gcc.c file, which handles starting the MCU before running the program. But I'm not sure how to bundle it.

There's a lot of files that are for different IDEs, but they're non-free, so I want to use the GNU tools.

I tried searching here in StackOverflow and Googling around, but I was unable to find an answer.

Comment: From a cursory look, I'd assume that you'd have to do two things. (1) compile startup_gcc.c to startup_gcc.o, with a modified version of the call to arm-none-eabi-gcc, followed by (2) modifying the call to arm-none-eabi-ld, such that it included startup_gcc.o  - never was much of a fan of (hand-generated) makefiles or cmd-line build process. You can (almost certainly) use the arm compiler with the Code::Blocks ide. I'd be inclined to use it to ease the build process. I have C::B, but find it difficult to justify a 50+ mb download to test the arm compiler with it. :-p

Comment: it has been a long time since I posted these http://lmistuff.blogspot.com/2008/01/blinker3.html I use github.com/dwelch67 now. Luminary micro was bought by ti, the product name stellaris remained after the ti purchase. none of my examples use the stellaris libraries or code, I cut through all of that and have very simple, low overhead,examples. all the source code is in the package, it does not rely on the compiler and its linker scripts or startup code. the raspberry pi directory has additional information (baremetal) that may shed more light on the use of the gnu tools for this kind of work

Answer (score 0):

I believe the linker is discarding the startup code.
A good way to make sure it gets included is using [KEEP](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html#SEC25) in your linker script. This will make sure the linker does not discard your startup code. If you don't have your startup code in a section, you need to do that first.